# line.split("[ ]+") means split with space?

Tags: java, string, split

Hello if i have txt file containing lines like:

```
newmtl material0
Ka 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Kd 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Ks 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Tr 1.000000
```

and it's being split like:

```
if(line.startsWith("Ks")){
String[] str=line.split("[ ]+");}
```

It returns

```
0.000000 
0.000000 
0.000000
```

How come "[ ]+" means split with spaces?? Couldn't find anything where this was referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[ ]` is a space within brackets. With a `+` added, it means "1 or more spaces." This is a [regular expression (click here to learn more)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

For example, `[abc]+` will match `aaa`, `acba`, `cbabcbab`, or any combination of one or more of the letters `a`, `b`, and `c`. The `[]` means "one of the things in here" and the `+` means "one or more."

More examples:

```
f[ao]o      will match "foo" and "fao"
ya+y        will match "yay" or "yaaaaay" or "yaaaaaaaaaaaay"
hooray[!1]+ will match "hooray!!!!" or "hooray!!1!!1!!!!1" or "hooray!111"
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.split()` takes a regex as an argument. And this one is poorly written, it could have been:

```
" +"
```

which is a regex matching one or more spaces.

This is documented [in the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

In this case, your question suggests that a space is required in the Regex. But what seems to be your intention is capturing `one or more spaces`.

Though you can write `" +"` for this, commonly, `"\n"` and `"\t"` are also considered for accuracy. Hence, you can use the expression:

```
"\s+"
```

which is represented in Java as:

```
"\\s+"
```

to avoid compiler errors.